# Is there a php function to add nofollow to a link?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm generating affiliate links to some images through the visual editor. I have no possibility to add the nofollow.

Given the URL of the link I wanted to know if there was the possibility of adding a php function in the functions.php file.

For example the link is

```
<a href="https://linkaffiliation" target="_blank">
```

I would like to become

```
<a href="https://linkaffiliation" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you show your code to generate that link? I imagine you could try using the same method for "rel" as used for "target".

Comment: I can not because it is not html code where I can intervene. is a Wp composer visual editor tool for generating animated images. I open, load the image and then select url and target. I have no possibility to set anything else. The generated code is the one you see in the example.

Comment: Therefore, I have to try to intercept the html string with the url (the same for all the affiliate links) and change it dynamically via php in the functions.php file.

Comment: Since you just specify the URL, it must be something else that generates the actual HTML. I assumed that it is some PHP code (maybe not yours). If you find that code, you would be able to modify it there.

Answer (score 0):

Might use this function: [wp_rel_nofollow](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_rel_nofollow/), but it needs to be applied to the right HTML content, probably through some filter (see [add_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) ).